# How to get to add more justified paragraph to right?

Tags: paragraphs

I need a configuration to similar this picture[image]

some idea in latex?

Comment: Welcome, pleas show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Please add a boilerplate list as a MWE and try to describe which dimensions exactly should have certain values, instead of showing a picture and say: "Can you replicate this?"

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! You could manipulate the `enumerate` environment with `enumitem` to get something of that sort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label = \large\bfseries\Roman*.,
                      ref   = \Roman*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{nosep,left=-0.5ex,
    label = \large\bfseries\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*,
ref =\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*} 
\newcommand\PseudoSection[2][]{\item {\large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#2}}\par}
\newcommand\PseudoSubSection[2][]{\item {\large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#2}}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \PseudoSection{Introduction}
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

 something about koala bears.
 \PseudoSection{Topic A}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \PseudoSubSection{Subtopic 1}
   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
   bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

   something about ducks and marmots.
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much you are great